# Power Automate Adaptive card does not display in my email

Tags: json, power-automate, adaptive-cards, power-platform

Hi I have been working with power automate to create an approval flow that is triggered by a power apps app. The email contains the json for an adaptive card used for storing  responses. When I receive the email I cannot see the adaptive card. I have created a profile on the action card dashboard and it has been more than 12 hours since I was approved. I have no idea what is going on.
The below is the JSON for my Adaptive card.

```
{   "type": "AdaptiveCard",   "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",   "version": "1.4",   "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": ⁠ Compose_Inputs × ⁠,
      "wrap": true,
      "id": "lblID"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": ⁠ Condition3_Value × ⁠,
      "wrap": true,
      "id": "lblGid"
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
      "choices": [
        {
          "title": "Approve",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "title": "Reject",
          "value": "2"
        }
      ],
      "placeholder": "Choose whether to accept or reject the declaration",
      "id": "cmbApproval"
    },
    {
      "type": "RichTextBlock",
      "inlines": [
        {
          "type": "TextRun",
          "text": "Enter the reason for a rejection here"
        }
      ],
      "id": "redtRejection"
    },
    {
      "type": "RichTextBlock",
      "inlines": [
        {
          "type": "TextRun",
          "text": "Reccomend some actions that need to be taken"
        }
      ],
      "id": "redtActionable"
    }   ],   "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Http",
      "title": "Submit",
      "id": "btnSubmit",
      "method": "POST",
      "body": "{\n\"Approval\" : \"{{cmbApproval.value}}\",\n\"Actions\": \"{{redtActionable.text}}\",\n\"Rejection\": \"{{redtRejection.text}}\",\n\"Approval_ID\":\"{{lblID.text}}\",\n\"Gift_ID\":\"{{lblGid.text}}\"\n}",
      "url": "https://prod-78.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/2ecc98c6673e4d88b2569fb6be6eae33/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=to-6fjShHwNxMqXywd-HNg5Wl-z95eiorM0w1ZyiZTs",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Authorization",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "name": "Content-type",
          "value": "application/json"
        }
      ],
      "originator": "1e643d3f-b41b-4723-b72d-23a5e813a5ba"
    }   ],   "id": "btnSubmit" }
```

Comment: Any errors or anything?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit later and I'm not sure if this will help. But after looking through the card I noticed you had a few formatting issues on your adaptive card and sometimes I've found that when my adaptive cards don't display properly it is because of formatting issues.

You could possibly try adding this:

```
   {
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.4",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Compose_Inputs ×",
      "wrap": true,
      "id": "lblID"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Condition3_Value ×",
      "wrap": true,
      "id": "lblGid"
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
      "choices": [
        {
          "title": "Approve",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "title": "Reject",
          "value": "2"
        }
      ],
      "placeholder": "Choose whether to accept or reject the declaration",
      "id": "cmbApproval"
    },
    {
      "type": "RichTextBlock",
      "inlines": [
        {
          "type": "TextRun",
          "text": "Enter the reason for a rejection here"
        }
      ],
      "id": "redtRejection"
    },
    {
      "type": "RichTextBlock",
      "inlines": [
        {
          "type": "TextRun",
          "text": "Recommend some actions that need to be taken"
        }
      ],
      "id": "redtActionable"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Http",
      "title": "Submit",
      "id": "btnSubmit",
      "method": "POST",
      "body": "{\n\"Approval\": \"{{cmbApproval.value}}\",\n\"Actions\": \"{{redtActionable.text}}\",\n\"Rejection\": \"{{redtRejection.text}}\",\n\"Approval_ID\": \"{{lblID.text}}\",\n\"Gift_ID\": \"{{lblGid.text}}\"\n}",
      "url": "https://prod-78.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/2ecc98c6673e4d88b2569fb6be6eae33/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=to-6fjShHwNxMqXywd-HNg5Wl-z95eiorM0w1ZyiZTs",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Authorization",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "name": "Content-type",
          "value": "application/json"
        }
      ],
      "originator": "1e643d3f-b41b-4723-b72d-23a5e813a5ba"
    }
  ],
  "id": "btnSubmit"
}
```